# Can I program Java with Flex Builder?

Tags: java, eclipse, flex-builder-3

I have no experience with Java, but I want to learn it. I have been using Flex Builder standalone for a few months now, and am familiar with eclipse now. So since Flex Builder is basically eclipse, can I program Java with the same copy or do I need a new installation of eclipse to program Java? Also if anyone can point me to a tutorial that shows how to setup eclipse to program Java that would be appreciated too. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick answer: Yes.

The full answer is described in detail here: http://www.suketuvyas.com/2007/09/10/java-development-in-flex-builder/

Comment: Thanks, that worked, btw can you point me to a "hello world" app tutorial with Java+Eclipse? Thanks!!